# Would Limnlight make sense instead of limelight?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I am familiar with the term limn:

> limn
>   /lim/Submit
>   verbLITERARY
>   past tense: limned; past participle: limned
>   depict or describe in painting or words.
>   suffuse or highlight (something) with a bright color or light.

I heard the phrased "limned in the same light" and immediately started wondering if I'd been spelling "limelight" wrong my entire life; looked it up to see if it was "limnlight".

> limelight (n.)
>   1826, popular name for Drummond light or calcium light, a brilliant light created by the incandescence of lime (n.1); adopted for lighthouses and later for the Victorian stage, where it illuminated the principal actors, hence the figurative use of the phrase in the limelight "on stage, at the center of attention" (1877).

Citrus is the correct mnemonic, but I can't help but wonder...

#### Could I use "limnlight" to convey the same meaning, despite the correct/accepted usage being "limelight"?

Comment: If you expect English vocabulary or spelling to "make sense", you will often be disappointed.  **limelight** .. intense white light obtained by heating a cylinder of lime, formerly used in theatres.  Unrelated to **limn** which goes back to Latin **luminare**.

Comment: Actually, **lime** here is calcium oxide, not the citrus fruit.

Comment: @GEdgar should I change the title to something else? such as "can I use Limnlight instead of limelight?"

Comment: Did you do any research about whether "limnlight" has ever been used in English, prior to asking here? What did that research show you?

Comment: @MarkBeadles I did not find anything exemplifying such usage, which brought me to ask about it here.

Comment: As your research shows, there is no English word 'limnlight', so you can't use it in correct English.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm almost certain that your logic doesn't hold up, unless you're using "correct English" to refer to "dictionary English", which is not my question.

Comment: I doubt it would be understood. I certainly wouldn’t understand it.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining what "limnlight" is to every person who runs into it, knock yourself out.

Comment: Calcium oxide (the "lime" here) isn't a fruit. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limelight).

Comment: @Laurel I'm aware? I don't understand the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. The **[limelight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limelight)** refers to the quicklime (calcium oxide) used to generate stage lighting. Its current use is most often figurative for appearing in the public eye.

**Limn**, as a kind of visual or figurative emphasis, lacks similar associations with acting or publicity. It's also not a common word: your own dictionary entry marks it as "literary" in use, which suggests that modern readers would most often encounter it in creative writing or literature. Furthermore, it's a verb, which breaks the compound pattern of *limelight*, which is formed from two nouns. Finally, its meaning connects it to portraying a subject in some kind of pigment, metal, or paint. That connects neither to the literal nor figurative context for **limelight**.

If you want to coin the term for your own use, it won't be read as a synonym for **limelight** and it may cause difficulty for readers or speakers who don't habitually read [Shakespeare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/limn-2009-10-13) and other literary authors.

Comment: I just learned that I've also been mispronouncing that word my entire life. Which led to most of my confusion.

Comment: How did you pronounce it? Curious minds want to know.

Comment: /lɪm'laɪt/, more or less.